# Get the process id from the service name using c#

Tags: c#, windows-services

Is there possibility to get the process id from the service name without using management object in c#? Management object is not working when WMI service is in error state.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help You.

```
SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name='MyServiceName'
```

Comment: This answer relies on WMI but the question explicitly excludes WMI-based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "sc.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "queryex \"" + srv_name + "\"";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.Close();
if (output.IndexOf("SERVICE_NAME") != -1)
{
    bool getPid = false;
    string[] words = output.Split(':');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if (word.IndexOf("PID") != -1 && getPid == false)
        {
            getPid = true;
        }
        else if (getPid == true)
        {
            string[] pid = word.Split('\r');
            return Convert.ToInt32(pid[0]);
        }
    }
}
```